# 3D Spline Interpolation in C# (surface interpolation)

Tags: c#, 3d, interpolation, spline

I have a `List<Point3D>` of coordinates, which represent points on a curved surface.
I want to increase the point density of the surface by adding points with a fixed x and y value.
The z component should be calculated by spline interpolation.

Is there a function or library in c# which can do this for me?

Comment: There is no built-in function for this. Actually, the best method depends on the characteristic of your point list. Can you give some details (e.g. how are the points distributed, is there a grid, is there always only one point for any x/y combination, do you know anything about continuity / smoothness of the surface...)?

Comment: When you want to research on how to create a curved surface from a list of points, you better use keywords such as "surface interpolation". Using "spline interpolation" to search is likely to give you more articles in the area of "creating a curve from a list of points".

Comment: @ Nico Schertler: The Surface looks like a slightly warped sheet of paper. The point list consists of the corners and the maxima/minima in respect to the z values. In most cases there is only one maximum, so it looks more like a cushion, but the solution should work for N minima and M maxima as well.

Comment: Is the grid of points structured or not?

Comment: A little late, but look at this: [3d Spline Code in C#](http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=9830.0)